# Transactions index in tezos

Tags: transactions, conseil

Currently the full node can offer details of transactions sitting in a queried block but it is not possible for it to provide infos on a particular transaction from its hash because the native tezos DB does not build an index based on transactions hash.

What are the options available to build such an index ? Ocaml pro has open sourced TzScan code but has anyone actually given it a go and been able to reconstruct its db ?

Is there other solutions which people have been experimenting with ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conseil is software that provides this functionality. Alongside ConseilJS you can easily use this with your applications. [Here](https://medium.com/@CryptonomicTech/conseil-and-conseiljs-are-now-in-beta-99c00d30a808) is a full article regarding Conseil. And you can view the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/Cryptonomic/Conseil).